# Remove labelled emails from Google Inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have an inbox, and a label (let's call it label x). When I get an email that matches the filter for label x, I want it to appear in the 'x' folder, and NOT appear in the inbox. And if possible, not get push notifications to my phone for it.

How can I achieve this in Gmail?

Basically this is for things like confirmations from Venmo or Amazon. Things I don't wanna NOT get the emails for, but things I don't necessarily need to see either.

Comment: Yep, this is a duplicate. I apologize! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the same filter where you're applying the label, check the "Skip the Inbox (Archive it)" option.